# Sublime Text 3 não reconhece comandos em PHP

Tags: sublime-text-3

Comecei a utilizar o Sublime Text 3 após certo tempo utilizando o BlueFish e me deparei com uma situação; os comandos em PHP não são executados pelo meu editor e, após uma longa pesquisa no Google e conversa com alguns amigos desenvolvedores, me falaram que deveria ser ativada certa opção para que o Sublime entenda o código PHP. Lá se foram 2 horas e ainda não consegui encontrar.

Alguém sabe onde seria esta opção, caso ela realmente exista, ou o meu editor que está com problemas? Inclusive, tenho um amigo que não está conseguindo executar JavaScript no Sublime também.

Comment: "`os comandos em PHP não são executados pelo meu editor`" O que isso quer dizer? Um editor de texto serve pra editar texto, é esperado que ele não execute nada.

Answer (score 2):

O sublime não executa php, nem mesmo o bluefish pelo que me lembro, o que você pode fazer é definir a sintaxe php padrão que vem com o sublime, ou baixar alguma que tenha modos de completar as funções. Recomendo PHP Syntax Checker. Para instalar basta pressionar Ctrl + Shift + P, após isso digitar "Install package" e digitar o nome do package "PHP Syntax Checker" e pronto, será instalado e já pode usar. Na internet você pode encontrar outros packages que são muitos produtivos.

Comment: Certo, me expressei de forma errada. Utilizo o Sublime para efetuar a edição, porém quando executo no navegador ele simplesmente não retorna os comandos escritos em php, somente em html.

Ele retorna "'php' não é reconhecido como um comando interno ou externo, um programa ou um arquivo em lotes"

Comment: Você tem o Apache PHP instalado? ou se tiver, conferiu se o serviço está rodando? Não trabalho muito com php, mas sei que tem que instalar alguns programas especificos para rodar um codigo php, e ele tem que estar em uma pasta especifica também. Segue link de como fazer a instalação no ubuntu (http://gilbertoalbino.com/como-instalar-php-7-no-ubuntu-via-apt-get/). A pasta aonde que tem que estar o seu projeto é var/www/html/nome-do-projeto. E para windows (https://blog.schoolofnet.com/2015/04/como-instalar-o-php-no-windows-do-jeito-certo-e-usar-o-servidor-embutido/)

Comment: E também verifique se configurou corretamente as variaveis de ambiente no windows, pois acho que é isso que está causando o seu problema.

Answer (score 1):

Ele não executa nada, é um editor de texto. Se quiser editar a Syntax, é só ir em view >> Syntax >> PHP

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]